# remove blank space owlcarousel 2 with loop false in first item

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

I intend to create slider with plugin owlcarousel2 and set loop to false, so it would stop looping and left last element blank which I wanted.

But somehow I want to remove blank space on first item or if its in first item.
am trying this way but it doesnt work well, any suggestion how to do better

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.slider-wrap').owlCarousel({
  center: true,
  items: 3,
  loop: false,
  margin: 10,
  nav: true,
  dots: false,
  touchDrag  : false,
  mouseDrag  : false
});

$('.slider-wrap .owl-stage').css('transform','translateX(0)');
$('.slider-wrap').on('changed.owl.carousel', function(e) {
var slidIndex = (e.item.index + 1) - e.relatedTarget._clones.length / 2;

if(slidIndex == 1){
  $('.slider-wrap .owl-stage').css('background-color','yellow');
  $('.slider-wrap .owl-stage').css('transform','translateX(0)');
}
});
});
```

```css
.item{
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="slider-container">
    <div class="slider-wrap owl-carousel">
     <div class="item">
      1
     </div>
     <div class="item">
      2
     </div>
     <div class="item">
      3
     </div>
     <div class="item">
      4
     </div>
     <div class="item">
      5
     </div>
     <div class="item">
      6
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

please add loop:true;

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.slider-wrap').owlCarousel({
  center: true,
  items: 3,
  loop: true,
  margin: 10,
  nav: true,
  dots: false,
  touchDrag  : false,
  mouseDrag  : false
});

$('.slider-wrap .owl-stage').css('transform','translateX(0)');
$('.slider-wrap').on('changed.owl.carousel', function(e) {
var slidIndex = (e.item.index + 1) - e.relatedTarget._clones.length / 2;

if(slidIndex == 1){
  $('.slider-wrap .owl-stage').css('background-color','yellow');
  $('.slider-wrap .owl-stage').css('transform','translateX(0)');
}
});
});
```

```css
.item{
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="slider-container">
    <div class="slider-wrap owl-carousel">
     <div class="item">
      1
     </div>
     <div class="item">
      2
     </div>
     <div class="item">
      3
     </div>
     <div class="item">
      4
     </div>
     <div class="item">
      5
     </div>
     <div class="item">
      6
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I deliberately set loop to false, because I dont want to loop slider. But how I can avoid first item into blank space